# Nginx reverse proxy location subfolder 404 error

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I feel like this is simple enough...

this works:

```
http://##.###.###.##:3000/folder/end_point
```

this does not:

```
http://##.###.###.##/folder/end_point
```

this works:

```
http://##.###.###.##:3000
```

AND this works:

```
http://##.###.###.##
```

My nginx configuration for the root is:

```
location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

and for the directory is:

```
   location /folder/ {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/folder/;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

I've also tried:

```
location /folder/(.*) {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/folder/$1;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it without `/` before folder`s name:

```
location /folder {
           proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/folder;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

Comment: unfortunately no luck :/